# OSGI Felix runs somtimes into ClassNotFoundException for static class called in Activator

Tags: java, classnotfoundexception, apache-felix, activator

We have some osgi bundles which we install on a felix osgi framework.

In the bundle Activator we perform some init stuff, like caling a static class which doe some other init stuff.

Sometimes but not very often and not reproducable we run into a ClassNotFoundException for this static class which for SURE is in the bundle.

So the question is, is there a reason why this class is not available at the moment of the Activator try to run this class?

Is there a difference between static and NON static classes. Because the problem is only for static classes.

we have different bundles with different static init classes which have always the same problem.

Is there a better way to run init stuff, outside from the Activator?